# Hadoop - is there a way to share custom counters between jobs?

Tags: hadoop

I'm running a MapReduce workflow, that currently consists of 2 chained MR tasks. In the first task the mappers write to a custom counter. I wish to read the value of this counter in the setup() method of the reducers in the 2nd task. When I do try to read the counter's value in the 2nd task, I get a value of `0`.

For clarity, each task has a driver code of its own, with its own `Configuration` and `Job`. The counter is defined as a `static enum` in the main driver class, which is responsible for chaining the task (and also to launch an EMR cluster instead of running the workflow locally in a single-node cluster setup).

I'm using Hadoop 2.7.3 and Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least 3 options:

- write counter value to hdfs file. delete it after job finishes.
- share the configuration between jobs, put counter value in configuration.
- read counter value from first job counters in main driver, put it in second job configuration

To read counter after job finishes:

```
long val = job.getCounters().getGroup("g").findCounter("c").getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks - I opted for option #1 since I don't want to share configurations between tasks, and since this would later be run on EMR and I wouldn't enjoy the benefit of patching things through the main driver.

Comment: Saving the counter to ZooKeeper is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the counter to ZooKeeper. Check [Hadoop Definitive Guide](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hadoop-the-definitive/9781449328917/ch14.html) for and example.